# How do I handle error inside a custom webpack loader?

Tags: webpack

I have a custom webpack loader that I am trying to get to output a more useful error.

Any error that happens will be due to the loader attempting to load another file that doesn't exist via `fs.readFileSync`

If I wrap this call in a try ... catch block then it will always fail. If I remove the try ... catch block then it works just fine, unless the file doesn't exist. This can happen from user error. My loader is parsing a json object, then loading a template file based on that object and passing another member of the object though that template before returning the whole thing.

The documentation gives no info on error handling inside a loader. Please help.

Comment: Could you use `fs.readFile` (async version)? If so, then you have more options as then you can shape the error object passed to webpack. Possibly another option would be to raise an error of your own (or let it fall through) and let webpack capture it.

Comment: There was a reason I didn't use fs.readFile I think it had to do with adding lots of complexity to the webpack loader. If someone knows webpack loaders and can show me some good documentation on making an async loader I could probably use the async fs call. But that doesn't really answer my question.
How do we handle errors in a webpack loader?

Comment: Given there are so many loaders around, I would dig some similar one and see how it handles it. I was suggesting above that you could let webpack capture the `Error` and shape it (capture, throw again). That would feel like a good first step.

Comment: I have checked a few, I am asking here because I haven't found any that do any error handling. Not saying that none do, just that none that I have found.

Comment: Did you try capturing/raising again? Based on that I would say the loaders leave error handling to webpack (i.e. it captures what you throw or pass through the callback).

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what you mean by capturing/raising again?

Comment: I mean `try { ... do something ... } catch(err) { throw new Error(err); /* shape error here */ }` kind of clause. So before letting webpack to catch the error, you would catch it first and alter the error message or so. I would need some example (git repo) to work against to help any better.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. If I do that then the loader always throws an error, if I don't do that then the loader works without error.

Comment: Can you link to your loader (assuming it's public)? Easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Unfortunately no. My loader didn't work list this and so I have reworked this functionality in order to work around this. I was hoping to avoid getting into debugging my code and I was more interested in actual guidelines for error checking with regard to webpack loaders.